# php determine timezone name from hours offset

Tags: php, database, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

I'm migrating old users table to the new database and in the old table, user timezone saved in the format like `4`, `4.5` or `-4`, `-4.5`  which means `UTC+04:00`, `UTC+04:30` and `UTC-04:00`, `UTC-04:30`. I want somehow convert it to the format I can later easily use by PHP to convert all dates to user timezone. I found method `timezone_name_from_abbr()` which is working for integers like this `timezone_name_from_abbr('', -4 * 3600, 0)` = `America/Halifax"`, but how to be with doubles, `timezone_name_from_abbr` expecting only integers? Also even with integers, it's now clear should I use DST or not when migrating concrete user. Any idea how I can determine timezone by hours offset?

Comment: I can canvert  double value to time zone using for exampe `timezone_name_from_abbr('', (int)(-4.5 * 3600), 0)` but there is values like `8.75` and  `timezone_name_from_abbr` can't recognize such timezone

Comment: umm, I do not see how it can help me so far. I do not need to save a date or time, I want to save user timezone in the format I can later easily use by PHP or other languages to convert any DateTime to that timezone, ideally is to format like this `America/New_York`.  You can point me out to the function I can use to convert for example 8.75 to `Australia/Eucla` b-z I do not see such function so fat. Thanks!

Comment: Basically, this cannot be done.  You need additional information, such as the user's location.

Comment: Okay, thanks. There is also latitude/longitude, It should be possible to get time zone by that

Comment: Yep! See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086962/how-to-get-a-time-zone-from-a-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates.  In particular, try https://github.com/minube/geo-timezone